# Non retina images – must I add them to xcode?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Because I made app (iphone) myself, with  200 images, I want not using non retina images.
It may be for me big problem to resize images for non retina display.
I don't have non retina display iphone, to test it.

Must I add non retina images to xcode, or not?
If I don’t add them, must I add  “@2x” to all images for retina?

I tried my best to find answer for my question but there was no clear answer.

---

Thx for answers.
I thing it will be better make non retina display images, than buy non retina device for testing how it looks.

I have another question:

Button background needs @2x images and non retina display background images?

Answer (score 2):

You must add non-retina images if the platform your targeting includes non retina devices (e.g. iOS 6 and earlier or iOS 7 iPad). If you do not, non-retina devices may not render your app correctly.

If you are not targeting a platform that supports non-retina devices (Eg iOS 7 iPhone), you may omit non-retina images. Your retina images will still need the "@2x" suffix in the file name for the system to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I read somewhere that if you do not include non-retina images, the iOS will use the @2x images, scale them on the fly to non-retina sizes, but that may affect performance. Make sure you test on at least one non-retina Device to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be too much of an issue. Test your app on the simulator using non retina and make sure your images are showing up properly. Your images should scale and won't cause a problem. It would be better if you could have both retina and non retina images but not a game beaker.